# Haskell declarations to mach a type scheme

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I'm wondering what Haskell type declarations would match the type scheme below?

∀a,b.H(a → b) ⇒ b

This is from [4.1 Unambiguity / A Theory of Overloading](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.8605&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

---

Later Edit after [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi)'s answer.
I tried out this code, but I can't make it fail as it should

```
class H f where 
  g :: f -> Bool

instance H (Integer -> Bool) where
  g f = f 0

instance H (Char -> Bool) where
  g f = f '1'

g (\x -> if x > 10 then True else False)

g (\x -> if x == '0' then True else False)
```

Also, I realized that for this code couldn't make the type unambiguous by adding a functional dependency like `| b -> a` to match this propagation rule

`(FH) H (a —> b),H (a' —> b) => a = a'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `H` is a typeclass name, it can admit multiple instances

```
instance H (Int -> Bool) where
instance H (Char -> Bool) where
...
```

In such case, if we have a term

```
x :: ∀a,b. H(a → b) ⇒ b
```

and we need to compute

```
x && True
```

we need to typecheck `x :: Bool`, but this only determines `b = Bool`, while both `a = Int` and `a = Char` could be used. The type is ambiguous because of that.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I realized my comment would be too big, so I've edited the original post. I still new to Haskell so I was not able to reproduce your answer in code. Could you please show me where I was wrong?

Comment: @jackmalkovick You assume that `g` is a method in the class, but `g` does not have to be a method, AFAICU. You can define, outside the class, `g :: ∀a,b. H(a → b) ⇒ b` as `g = undefined`. GHC will complain that the type is ambiguous. Even if you force to accept it by turning on a GHC extension, `g && True` will trigger an error, I think.